# Undefined offset: 1 error issue when select from drop down list

Tags: php, laravel

I write a function as below: and wonder why got this error? When the 
**cat_id and price selected** is fine. **Price selected** also go well. Just when i choose only the **Categories** it doesn't any effect and show the error  **Undefined offset: 1**

```
public function productsCat(Request $request){
    $cat_id = $request->cat_id;
    $price = explode("-",$request->price);

    $start = $price[0];
    $end = $price[1];

    if($cat_id!="" && $price!="0"){
        $data = DB::table('products')
            ->join('cats','cats.id','products.cat_id')
            ->where('products.cat_id',$cat_id)
            ->where('products.pro_price', ">=", $start)
            ->where('products.pro_price', "<=", $end)
            ->get();

    }

    else if($price!=""){
        $data = DB::table('products')
            ->join('cats','cats.id','products.cat_id')
            ->where('products.pro_price', ">=", $start)
            ->where('products.pro_price', "<=", $end)
            ->get();
    }
    else if($cat_id!=""){
        $data = DB::table('products')
            ->join('cats','cats.id','products.cat_id')
            ->where('products.cat_id',$cat_id)
            ->get();
    }
    else{
        return "<h1 align='center'>Please select at least one filter from drop down list</h1>";

    }
    if(count($data)=="0"){
        echo "<h1 align='center'>no products found under this Category</h1>";
    }else{
        return view('front.productsPage',[
            'data' => $data, 'catByUser' => $data[0]->cat_name
        ]);
    }
```

}

Comment: `Log::info($price);` It most likely only has 1 value instead of two.

Comment: may i know is the code problem?

Comment: Undefined offset means there's an empty array key . so  yes code problem, you are trying to get an array key which does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

use this code it will work for you

```
public function productsCat(Request $request){
    $cat_id = $request->cat_id;
    $price = explode("-",$request->price);

    $start = $price[0];
    $end = $price[1];


    $data = DB::table('products');
    if (!empty($cat_id)) {
        $data->join('cats','cats.id','products.cat_id')
            ->where('products.cat_id',$cat_id);
    }
    if(!empty($start) && !empty($end)){
        $data->where('products.pro_price', ">=", $start)
            ->where('products.pro_price', "<=", $end)
    }
    $data->get();
    if(empty($cat_id) && empty($request->price))
    {
        return "<h1 align='center'>Please select at least one filter from drop down list</h1>";

    }
    if(count($data)==0){
        echo "<h1 align='center'>no products found under this Category</h1>";
    }
    else
    {
        return view('front.productsPage',[
            'data' => $data, 'catByUser' => $data[0]->cat_name
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: tried. but result is incorrect.

Comment: what was incorrect to your needs

Comment: now when price selected will return to else section